# SQLite: how to name columns in a "values" subselect

Tags: sqlite

In postgres I can say:

```
test=# select * from (values(1),(3),(7)) as foo(id);
 id
----
  1
  3
  7
(3 rows)
```

This means that such a subselect can subsequently be joined with other tables using foo.id etc.

In sqlite I can say:

```
sqlite> select * from (values(1),(3),(7)) as foo;

----------
1
3
7
```

but if I say foo(id) I'll get an error:

```
sqlite> select * from (values(1),(3),(7)) as foo (id);
Error: near "(": syntax error
```

Obviously with usual subselects (e.g. "(select ... as a, ... as b from... ) as foo" ) you could simply name each field.

The only simple workaround I've found to name columns in such a situation is to do an union like:

```
sqlite> select * from (select 1 as id where 1=0 union values(1),(3),(7)) foo;
id        
----------
1         
3         
7
```

Is there a better way to name columns in this kind of "subselects" in SQLite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns created by VALUES have names that you would not want to use (although it's possible):

```
sqlite> .mode columns
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> select * from (values(1,2,3));
            :1          :2        
----------  ----------  ----------
1           2           3         
sqlite> select "", ":1", ":2" from (values(1,2,3));
            :1          :2        
----------  ----------  ----------
1           2           3
```

This cannot be changed; there is no better way than to prefix a 'real' SELECT with UNION ALL.

Comment: Ah, I see, so the column I had was actually accessible through "" - great. And the only way to rename is then probably either one more level of subselecting (not a biggie, considering you would not use "values" with a huge list) 

    sqlite> select "" as col1, ":1" as col2, ":2" as col3 from (values(1,2,3));

or an union. 

Clear. Thanks.