# How to select values with a column alias?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I do this in SQLite3:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS "tbl.col"
WHERE "tbl"."col" = 1
```

I get: no such column: tbl.col

What is the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS tbl(col)
WHERE tbl.col = 1;
```

Note that when you escape an identifier (using `"tbl.col"`), then that is *one* name that has a period in it.  Not two names.

EDIT:

I would have expected the above to work, but it doesn't in SQLite.  One alternative is to use a CTE:

```
with tbl(col) as (
      VALUES (1), (2), (3)
     )
SELECT *
FROM tbl
where tbl.col = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you wrote and I get back: near "(": syntax error:

Comment: Also, I am using DB Browser for SQLite to test. Is it possible this is a limitation of that tool?

Comment: Yeah I was able to confirm other SQLite tools report the same error using the syntax you provide. For example, this online SQLite tool: [link](http://wdbengine.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Agendum . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me. I just faced this again and ultimately my answer below is what worked in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416690/sqlite-how-to-name-columns-in-a-values-subselect) which answers my question.

```
SELECT "tbl"."" AS "col"
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS "tbl"
```

Basically, in a VALUES the first column name is an empty string "", the second is ":1", third is ":2" and so forth...

Hope this helps somebody else.